# How do i recognize particular sound frequency in j2me?

Tags: java-me, audio

I just want to detect the particular sound in j2me. Is it possible? Or is there any another way...?

Answer (score 0):

use an Fast Fourier Transformation (FFT) for doing frequency analysis